# Custom layout and styles in ionic framework

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework

I am building my first application with ionic framework.. and I am having some issues with layouts.

I have this design and I don't know where to start to be able to easily do it in a standard way.

[image]

Comment: i would start by reading their css docs, you can also edit the ionic css file to tweak their style. You can also combine all of their css components in crazy ways, just experiment. Also the row col grid is extremely powerful. their docs are here. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Comment: Thanks I did that already I just wanted to have an easy way instead of writing new css code..

Comment: I know, i hate writing css code haha